# Winsock leitura de dados remotos (CMD)

Tags: c++, socket

tenho um servidor (remoto) onde redireciona sua shell para o client(remoto), o lado cliente esta usando netcat ou telnet para a comunicação.
Estou desenvolvendo o lado cliente para uso com Windows, porém estou tendo alguns problemas na hora de receber os dados do servidor, eles estão vindo incompleto, e também não consigo enviar comandos mais do que 2 vezes para o servidor.

a aplicação deve enviar comandos remotos para a shell  (send), e receber os dados (recv) ate que o client deseje sair.
o problema é  receber os dados completos do servidor...

o que deve ser feito para melhorar esta aplicação?

```
while (1)
{
    //READ
    memset(pbuf, 0, sizeof(pbuf));
    iResult = recv(client[iD].socket, pbuf, sizeof(pbuf) - 1, 0);
    if (iResult < 0)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            continue;
        }

        printf("recv error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
    {
        printf("disconnected\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)
        {
            std::cout << pbuf[i];
        }
        memset(pbuf, 0, sizeof(pbuf));

        //SEND
        memset(key_buffer, 0, sizeof(key_buffer));
        fgets(key_buffer, sizeof(key_buffer) - 1, stdin);
        if (!strcmp(key_buffer, "exit"))
            break;
        iResult = send(client[iD].socket, key_buffer, sizeof(key_buffer) - 1, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            CLEAN_UP();
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tente usar o código disponível neste link: [The overdue NetSock release](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=426)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Receber os dados completos do servidor", provavelmente o problema deve estar nesse buffer que você esta usando **"pbuf"** deve estar lotando, ou então pode não estar sendo manipulado de forma adequada durante o processo.
tenta criar uma função para receber e enviar dados pra essa Shell.

**Exemplo:**

```
while (1)
{
    if (ReadShell(client[iD].socket) == 3)
        break;
}
```

**tenta usar isso para leitura de dados:**

```
char chunk[1024] = "";

    memset(chunk, 0, sizeof(chunk));
    if ((iResult = recv(client[iD].socket, chunk, 1024, 0)) < 0)
    {   
        std::cout << "Falha ao receber dados do servidor" << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return 3;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++)
        {
            if (chunk[i] != NULL)
                printf("%c", chunk[i]);
        }
    }
```

**E isso para enviar os dados:**

```
  char message[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
        Sleep(500);
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
        fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
        if (send(client[iD].socket, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Falha ao enviar dados.");
            getchar();
            return 3;
        }

        if (!strcmp(message, "exit\n"))
        {   
            std::cout << "\nFinalizando Shell..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            return 3;
        }
```